# Configure IntelliJ to understand Gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

IntelliJ (12.1.6) has Gradle support, but it seems to only extend to running the scripts. It doesn't seem to understand the Gradle code itself like it does with something like Ant. For instance, any "task" or "apply" or other Gradle-ism keywords are unknown.

Can IntelliJ be configured to understand Gradle code? Again, not to run it, but to actually parse the file and present it intelligently with things like auto-completion. I know Gradle uses Groovy, which IntelliJ supports very well, but I can't seem to find what I'd need to configure/import to get it to understand Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle support in IntelliJ 12 is very limited, and there is nothing you can do about it. IntelliJ 13 (EAP) vastly improves on this and already offers some auto-completion.